# GKAchievement reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler: crash

Tags: ios, game-center

Everyone once in a while I will get crash reports for my App (via crittercism) with the following NSInvalidArgumentException crash:

```
+[GKAchievement reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3f940a84
```

The code looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *achivementArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

for (NSString *achievementID in achievementsToUpload) // achievementsToUpload is a NSSet
{
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:achievementID];
    if (achievement)
    {
        ...

        [achivementArray addObject:achievement];
    }
}

[GKAchievement reportAchievements:achivementArray withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error sending achievement: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

If the error is indeed inside reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:, as far as I can see, the source of the error can come from two places: 1) achivementArray is not an NSArray or 2) error is not really an NSError.

In the case of #1, I create the array a few lines above the call and in case #2, I doubt the OS is sending back a non-NSError object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header looks like:

```
+ (void)reportAchievements:(NSArray *)achievements withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionHandler __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

So the issue may be in base sdk that you are using. This method is available starting from iOS 6.0.

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.  Don't know how I missed that.